# Effect of page turning

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

There's any alternative for UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp and  UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown, me need auto effect page turning like in real book.

Thanks,
Roman

Answer (score 1):

If you’re a member of the iOS Developer Program (and as such have early access to the iOS 5 SDK), look up the docs for UIPageViewController.

Comment: …How would you do this pre iOS 5?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn’t—it’s kind of a pain. But there’s been a lot of work done on recreating the iBooks page-turning effect; searching for that here or on Google should turn up a number of examples.

Comment: If you want to do it pre iOS 5 you could take a look at the Leaves project. http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/84963-github-leaves-project.html